# AJAX запрос ошибка: XMLHttpRequest cannot load a page. Redirect from a page to another page has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript

Как произвести ajax запрос?
При простейшем коде выдает ошибку:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://google.com",
    success: function() {
    alert('asd');           }
});
```

Ошибка

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load google.com/. Redirect from 'google.com/' to 'http://www.google.com/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: Прочитайте про кроссдоменные ajax запросы. https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Answer (score 1):

Произвести Ajax запрос на другой домен **не получится** без указания на другом домене специальной политики (CORS), во всех современных браузерах действует [правило ограничения домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), которое гласит, что можно выполнять ajax запросы только на ресурсы, у которых совпадает с ресурсом отправителя следующие параметры:

1. домен;
2. порт;
3. протокол.

Comment: Не только совпадает. Ресурс `example.com` может открыть доступ к нему с домена `example123.com` и тогда `example123.com` сможет свободно обмениваться запросами с `example.com`

Comment: @mix Ну да, с помощью CORS, но можно еще proxy_pass через nginx прокинуть на нужный домен и без разрешения))

Comment: Ну это серверный обход CORS, а "правильным" путем только так.

Comment: Есть ли всё таки решение моей проблемы?

Comment: и как правильно составить AJAX запрос?